# Number of cells in array covered by a random permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-permutations

Consider a set $A \subseteq [n] \times [n]$ with $|A| = a = \alpha n$ for some $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

Suppose we select a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ uniformly at random. This permutation $\pi$ can also be viewed as a subset of $[n] \times [n]$. Then the random variable $|\pi \cap A|$ is the number of cells of $A$ meeting $\pi$, i.e. the number of pairs $(x,y) \in A$ with $\pi(x) = y$.

My question is this: for some fixed value $r \geq 2$ and fixed value of $\alpha$,  and letting $n \rightarrow \infty$, what is the maximum value of
$$
q_{A} = \Pr( | \pi \cap A| \geq r) 
$$
asymptotically in $n$ ?

It seems reasonable that $q_{A}$ should be maximized when $A = \{ (1,1), (2,2), \dots, (a,a) \}$, since this maximizes the expected value of $\binom{ |\pi \cap A|}{ r }$. (It is important here that $\alpha \leq 1$.) In this case, $\pi \cap A$ roughly has a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda = \alpha$ (bearing in mind that $\alpha$ and $r$ are constant), and so we would expect
$$
q_{A} \leq (1+o(1)) \sum_{j \geq r} e^{-\alpha} \alpha^j / j!
$$

Is this intuition correct? Is it true that $q_{A}$ satisfies such bound for any fixed $r$ and $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Isn't the probability the same for all "partial permutation matrices", i.e, where A has $\alpha n$ entries in different rows and columns? And if two entries are in the same row/column, no permutation can hit both these entries at the same time.

Comment: For $r=1$, the probability is maximised when $A$ lies in one row or in one column, as all hits of its elements are disjoint in this case.

Comment: @ Per, yes it's the same for all partial permutation matrices.

Comment: @ Ilya, you are correct, I will edit the problem to specific $r \geq 2$